# What's the right way to set-up real-time backup for an SQL Server database and/or ASP.Net MVC Entity transactions?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, backup, high-availability

I am developing an application (a web application with ASP.Net MVC 4 and Entity Framework 5) that is to deal with financial transactions (in a pretty high-load mode) and can not afford a single transaction to be forgotten once committed, which  makes ordinary scheduled backups almost useless. How is this to be done in such a case?

Comment: well that all depends on some unknown factors like: transaction volume, used database system ()edition and version), your availability strategy, number of datacenters etc. You make like to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee523927%28v=sql.100%29.aspx for some high availability scenarios using sql server 2008 (I just suppose you use sql server 2008)

Comment: What are you trying to protect against?  Unexpected reboot of sql server?  Hard disk failure? Tornado taking out your data center?

Comment: @StrayCatDBA, yes I am trying to protect against the scenarios you have mentioned.

Comment: @BernhardKircher, we shall buy whatever editions needed for reliable functioning. We develop against the latest SQL Server 2012. Regarding the number of datacenters - we plan to have one IIS server for the application (covered with an nginx server), one primary DB server and a couple of secondary DB servers in different datacenters to get protected against localised emergencies like fire or terrorists attack.